# How should I update a TinyMCE plugin using tiny_mce_popup.js for version 4?

Tags: tinymce

TinyMCE4 documentation is currently dismal. I have an insert image plugin compatible with Ruby on Rails but it relies on the deprecated tiny_mce_popup.js. There's no information for how I should update a plugin to circumvent use of that file.

Comment: save yourself the trouble and wait till tinymce 4 gets out of beta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TinyMCE 3 was reliant on tiny_mce_popup.js for exchanging variables between the parent and dialogue. TinyMCE 4 does away with dialog.htm and with tiny_mce_popup.js

If you have a look at the [image plugin](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/4.x/js/tinymce/plugins/image/plugin.js), following `editor.windowManager.open` you can see the dialogue is created through JS alone. This eliminates the need for goofy access to parent variables through `opener`. If you can, stick with this template method.

I chose to stick with dialog.htm but I served it from rails so I wouldn't have deal with exchanging the form auth_token with JS. If you do this, remember that inserting your content should come from the plugin and not from your dialogue. This is my simple image uploader :

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('railsupload', function(editor, url) {
  var win, data, dom = editor.dom

  // Add a button that opens a window
  editor.addButton('railsupload', {
    icon: 'image',
    tooltip: 'Insert image',
    onclick: showDialog
  });

  function showDialog() {
    win = editor.windowManager.open({
      title: 'Insert image',
      name: 'railsupload',
      url: '/attachments/tinymce?owner_type=' + editor.settings.owner_type + '&owner_id=' + editor.settings.owner_id,
      width: 200,
      height: 220,
      bodyType: 'tabpanel',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Insert',
        onclick: submitForm
      }]
    });
  }

  function submitForm() {
    editor.insertContent("<img src=\"" + self.frames[1].document.img_url + "\" />")
    win.close()
  }
});
```

You'll need a rails attachments controller and you'll need to pass your attachment init params through the url. If I build this out in a gem, it will be compatible with [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) and I'll update this answer.

**Update**: TinyMCE now has this page on migrating from 3.x: [http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial:Migration_guide_from_3.x](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial%3aMigration_guide_from_3.x)

Answer (score 12):

TinyMCE 4 deprecates the old [`file_browser_callback`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:file_browser_callback) in favor of the new [`file_picker_callback`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:file_picker_callback) which has the advantage that it can return metadata.

```js
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
    file_picker_callback: function (callback, value, meta) {
        myFilePicker(callback, value, meta);
    },
    plugins: ['link image'],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image'
});

function myFilePicker(callback, value, meta) {
    tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        title: 'File Manager',
        url: '/Site/FileManager?type=' + meta.filetype,
        width: 650,
        height: 550,
    }, {
        oninsert: function (url) {
            callback(url);
        }
    });
}
```

In your file browser to return the file to the main page you call `mySubmit('/images/file_123.jpg')` when you click on a hyperlink or a image.

```js
function mySubmit(url) {
    top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams().oninsert(url);
    top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
}
```

Comment: It will be good if you write some tutorial or detail explanation with images. Because original information form documentation is too short. Thank you.