# TinyMCE 4 onchange event not fired

Tags: javascript, tinymce, dom-events, onchange

I use the `file_browser_callback` option. Just like this [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/cjdaab) in the [documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:file_browser_callback). I edited the sample so it gives an imageurl back and not a hard string. See for this the following [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/cjdaab/254).

The problem is that when you hit the button, the url of the image is set but when you leave the field, the change event isn't fired. Because of that, the image dimension aren't calculated. The event in the "image" plugin that should be fired is `srcChange`. When you paste the imageurl by hand in the textbox and leave the field, the change event does get fired and the dimensions of the image are calculated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `file_browser_callback` is depricated. You have to use the `file_picker_callback` instead. When I searched for the `file_picker_callback`, I saw the following question. 
[TinyMCE4 file_picker_callback - return additional params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900018/tinymce4-file-picker-callback-return-additional-params)

This gave me the answers to create a working filepicker.